# How to use the gradle to build appcompat(support v7) by myself?

Tags: android, intellij-idea, gradle, android-support-library, android-appcompat

I'm having a problem building APKs in IntelliJ using gradle.Because I import the appcompat library and use the android-library to build it by myself.There are no build errors and output the apk successful.But when you install the apk to phone which has Android 2.3,the action bar is fullscreen.But api >= 14 is totally normal.like this

wrong link:

[image: https:\drive.google.com/file/d/0B0RLAz3J2LuGR1E3NE9JblRIX1E/view?usp=sharing]

right link:

[image: https:\drive.google.com/file/d/0B0RLAz3J2LuGRUZvWlcxLWw5WXc/view?usp=sharing (please replace "\" use "//")]

But if I use the appcompat library by importing dependency,the apk is normorl.So my problem is why I can’t build appcompat by hand?

Here is my project structure

picture link:

[image: https:\drive.google.com/file/d/0B0RLAz3J2LuGVDg2Qmc4eVhERUk/view?usp=sharing (please replace "\" use "//")]

the root project’s build.gradle:

```js
buildscript {

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.1'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
//    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.1.0"
    compile project(":appcompat")
}

ext {
    compileSdkVersion = 21
    buildToolsVersion = "21.1.2"
}

android {

    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
    }
    
     lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
        }
    }
}
```

appcompat project’s build.gradle:

```js
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.1'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
    compile files('libs/android-support-v7-appcompat.jar')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
        }
    }
}
```

settings.build:

```
include ':appcompat'
```

Besides,I use gradle 2.2.1,support-v7 19.1.0.
The whole project can download here:
[project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0RLAz3J2LuGSG02ZzhqRV81bmc/view?usp=sharing)

Anyone who know this?

Answer (score 2):

Just add to dependencies:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
```

You shouldn't include jar's of the libraries that are available via repositories.

***Note***: Don't forget to update the support libraries in SDK Manager.

Comment: Thanks,I know what you said is right and everything works well.But what I said is totally not workable? Is there any way can make it work?